# How to get each value from table in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I get each value but it doesn't display on DSChiTiet. How can I fix it? It only gets value TenKH, NgayLap, TongTien.

DSChiTiet doesn't get value from table and displays null. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijFoA.png)

Thank you very much for your help <3.

My model PhieuBanHangModel

```
public class PhieuBanHangViewModel
{
    public int MaPBH { get; set; }
    public string TenKH { get; set; }
    public DateTime NgayLap { get; set; }
    public decimal TongTien { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CT_PhieuBanHangViewModel> DSChiTiet { get; set; }
}
```

My model CT_PhieuBanHangModel

```
public class CT_PhieuBanHangViewModel
{
    public int MaPBH { get; set; }
    public int MaSP { get; set; }
    public int SoLuong { get; set; }
    public decimal DonGia { get; set; }
    public decimal ThanhTien { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Create Json

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create(PhieuBanHangViewModel phieuBanHang)
    {

        return Json(data: "", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Function in View

```
function ThanhToan() {
        var phieuBanHang = {};
        var dsct_PhieuBanHang = new Array();
        phieuBanHang.TenKH = $("#txtTenKH").val();
        phieuBanHang.NgayLap = $("#txtNgayGiaoDich").val();
        phieuBanHang.TongTien = $("#txtTongTien").val();

        $("table tr:not(:first)").each(function () {
            var ct_PhieuBanHang = {};
            ct_PhieuBanHang.MaSP = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(0))").text());
            ct_PhieuBanHang.SoLuong = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(4))").text());
            ct_PhieuBanHang.DonGia = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(6))").text());
            ct_PhieuBanHang.ThanhTien = parseFloat($(this).find("td:eq(7))").text());
            dsct_PhieuBanHang.push(ct_PhieuBanHang);

        });
        phieuBanHang.DSChiTiet = dsct_PhieuBanHang;
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(phieuBanHang),
            url: '/Manager/CT_PhieuBanHang/Create',
            success: function (data) {
            },

            error: function () {
                alert('Lỗi');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Try changing `IEnumerable` to `List`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  Thank you for your help, but I tried and it doesn't change :(

Comment: Can you check using some network tracer what json data is passed to the controller? Or you can log in console and observe the value. Can you also share the json value here?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I attached image in my question. DSChiTiet doesn't receive value from my table. Could you please see problems? I'm so grateful

Comment: I asked for the json value which goes from Ajax to server. You are receiving null collection, that is all clear. That's why I need to see what json is being sent from Ajax to server. Can you share the json?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to inherit `ApiController`and add the `[FromBody]` attribute to the binding model:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    /* something else... */

    // /Manager/CT_PhieuBanHang/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Create([FromBody] PhieuBanHangViewModel phieuBanHang)
    {
        return Json(data: "", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    /* something else... */
}
```

For your jQuery code, make sure thet:`$("table tr:not(:first)")` do returns an array contains at least 1 item. (You can verify that by doing a `console.log(phieuBanHang)` to print out your data).